# Can I use Mercury Editor without an specific Pages Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mercury-editor

I want to use Mercury Editor (https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury) to edit posts in the blog area of my RoR application. I don't have any Pages model, I just want to edit posts and not all the site's pages.

In my routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
    member { post :mercury_update }
end
```

In my posts_controller.rb:

```
def mercury_update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.name = params[:content][:page_name][:value]
    post.content = params[:content][:page_content][:value]
    post.save!
    render text: ""
end
```

And also did:

```
$(window).bind('mercury:ready', function() {
  var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
  Mercury.saveURL = link.data('save-url');
  link.hide();
});

$(window).bind('mercury:saved', function() {
  window.location = window.location.href.replace(/\/editor\//i, '/');
});
```

And changed save style to 'form' in mercury.html.erb.

Even following those steps, I'm getting this error over and over when I try to save changes in a test post:

> Mercury was unable to save to the url: http://localhost:3000/blog/test

Comment: Looks like your SaveURL isn't getting set right. What's the 'save-url' on #edit_link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem too with the javascript not loading. I would suggest to consider putting the javascript overrides into the /app/assets/javascript/mercury.js inside the onload area. Here is what mine looks like:

```
onload: function() {
$(window).bind('mercury:ready', function() {
  var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
  Mercury.saveURL = link.data('save-url');
  link.hide();
});
},
```

Another option is to put the override code inside the file /app/assets/javascript/mercury_override.js, like so:

```
$(window).bind('mercury:ready', function() {
  var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
  Mercury.saveURL = link.data('save-url');
  link.hide();
});
```

I think the 2nd solution is a better one as this would not be touched by the any updates applied from the mercury updates.

Answer (score 1):

Mercury.saveUrl = link.data('save-url');

Comment: Note the case of `Mercury.saveUrl`. It was renamed from `Mercury.saveURL`.